# Disable automatic Detekt run in Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, detekt

I have added [Detekt](https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/kotlindsl.html) to my Gradle project. My intention was to invoke `detekt` on demand only, since it creates a lot of false positives. However, the `detekt` task is active by default (and breaks the build). How can I avoid this dependency?

What I tried: I have added a `gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask` block that sets `enabled = false` conditionally:

```
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask {
    val containsDetektTaskCall = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("detekt")
    if (name.startsWith("detekt") && !containsDetektTaskCall) {
        logger.lifecycle("Skipping all 'detekt-plugin' tasks")
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that these 7 lines of code are really a bit much just to override a task dependency. I would appreciate a general Gradle answer as well as some Detekt-specific way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to skip the task.
The easiest one is to add `onlyIf` condition for your task.
For example:

```
task detect {
    doFirst {
        println 'detect'
    }
}

detect.onlyIf { project.hasProperty('runDetect') }
```

The `detect` task will be executed only when the `onlyIf` condition is true.

```
./gradlew detect -PrunDetect
```

Please take a look here for details https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:skipping_tasks

Comment: For reference: For the Kotlin DSL, it’s `tasks.getByPath("detekt").onlyIf { project.hasProperty("runDetekt") }`.

Comment: And, better still, since it is awkward to add one more command line parameter: `tasks.getByPath("detekt").onlyIf { gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("detekt") }`

Comment: Yet better, you can put it in any order or any subproject (like :mysubproject:detekt):     
 `tasks.getByPath("detekt").onlyIf { gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("detekt") } } `